How do we determine the reverse transmission factor of a feedback amplifier if it consists of multiple feedback components?

In this feedback circuit we can see that there are two feedback components,$$R_E$$ and $$R_F$$. If there were no $$R_F$$ then this would have been current sampling-voltage mixing and if there were no $$R_E$$ then this would have been voltage sampling-current mixing. But due to the presence of both of this components, it has become quite tough to determine which one is to be considered? If we consider that this circuit belongs to both of the topologies, then how should we determine the reverse transmission factor?

It depends on your priorities. (i.e. specs) There are tradeoffs for gain, offset and impedance (I/O).
Vcc (fixed, low, high, variable)?  power gain or voltage gain?  Linearity/THD eliminate saturation Vce? max output swing?  Each has a different Rule of Thumb or simplification to design. but expect a gain of 10 to 30 for Av with this improvement in linearity. So what are your priorities? specs?

another spec is BW ?  DC coupled from 0Vdc input or ?  GBW = ?  hFE options ?

If you can define a general spec I can show you how to optimize it.

I'm basically more into learning the gain, input and output resistances after the inclusion of feedback

did U try my sim? to get a gain of 30

Dual Feedback Transistor Biasing a Common Emitter Amplifier is a similar question but forgot to include the source impedance, which is critical in the determination of Av.
This method of negative feedback (NFB) ratio of Rf/Rin-Av improves linearity (THD & stability of the operating point) while offering several other features at the expense of reduced closed-loop gain. The open-loop gain depends on Re going to 0, while the open-loop gain increases with Vbe and Ic. Naturally, with NFB, the Av depends on the Aol being very high with hFE and increased Ic in order to approach the AvRfb/Rin.
Since the Q point is desired near the Vcc/2 for maximum swing a standard H biased-CE amplifier sufferers from clipping when the Ic is starved of current over a wide range and thus has the characteristic waning of voltage gain at rapidly reducing currents. To achieve this balanced Q-point Vcc will have a significant impact on the balance. Thus it becomes necessary to raise Ib to being down Vce to Vcc/2 with ratios of Vcc/Vbe greater than the closed loop gain, AV and pulling down base current for low Vcc/Vbe ratios.
The advantage of NFB here is that it can be DC coupled with a bipolar source but if AC coupled on the input, source impedance still matters but Vce will drop if Rin is not sourced to 0V so a fixed Rb to ground is needed to raise Vce.
Thus you still have DC bias issues for centering the Q point so the real advantage of this design is a significant reduction of nonlinearity from 10% full swing to 0.1%.  This is so because the NFB reduces the Vbe modulation with much better performance than H-biased emitter degeneration.
If you need 1% to 0.1% THD, this simple design is an acceptable solution.
I equate the total harmonic distortion (THD) by the peak asymmetry on a sine wave
\$THD=(V_{+p} + V_{-p})/ V_{pp} *100%\$
Realistically you still want to avoid cut-off with 1~2V of margin on a full swing but now you can get closer to saturation voltage to excellent linearity. So the Q point will be below Vcc/2 unless you need to operate at a low Vcc such as 3.3V or 5V.
The other tradeoff is NFB reduces input impedance to essentially Rin due to NFB reducing the base impedance and Vbe voltage swing.
Here I present Av=10 with hFE ~ 300 (2N5088) and THD = 0.1%  The other advantage of low gain is high BW.

Any Questions?

Here is my simple approach:
You can treat the two feedback loops successively. That means:
1.) Find the voltage gain of the stage using Re-feedback only A1=-gmRc/(1+gmRe)
2.) Create a forward gain block (gain A1) with a negative feedback loop consisting of Rf and the parallel combination (Rs||rin) - similar to an opamp inverter configuration. Consider Rc as a finite output source impedance. The dynamic resistance rin is the amplifiers input resistance at the base (increased due to Re-feedback). This feedback scheme gives the total closed-loop gain Acl.
Depending on parts values (Rs, Rf) it can be necessary to further reduce the total gain due to the forward path Rs-Rf which causes a corresponding non-inverted portion of the ouput voltage at the collector node.
Regarding your last question (reverse transmission factor=feedback factor Hr) you can find Hr by calculating backwards from Acl=HfAo/(1+HrAo). Here Ao is the gain without any feedback and Hf is the forard damping due to the path Rs-Rf.
